# Отслеживание запросов MySQL с помощью Python

Tags: python, mysql

Есть бд на MySQL в которую с некоторой периодичностью добавляются данные. Нужно как то отследить запросы на добавление, и как только такой запрос приходит, отправлять данные куда нибудь. Если с отправлением разберусь, то как постоянно отслеживать запросы и не загружать при этом сервер не могу понять.

Comment: Казалось бы, причем здесь python? Смотрите в сторону триггеров в MySQL. А дальше, можете вызывать внешний скрипт, когда триггер срабатывает. Например: http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html

Comment: Python рассматривал только в качестве отправки новых записей в телеграм. Спасибо, кажется это то, что нужно